# xcode , iphone animation effect setAnimationPosition

Tags: iphone, xcode, position, uiviewanimationtransition

is there any other method other than

> [UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPoint(0,0)];

i'm implementing the 'suck effect' but the effect keeps going to the top left hand corner .

i want the effect to be 'sucked' to a specific position .

setAnimationPosition seems like the way but it isnt working / depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{CGAffineTransform transform= CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(170, 20);
        [myImage setTransform:transform];
    } completion:nil];
```

If you want to have a better effect add this to the code:

```
 CGAffineTransformMakeScale(myScale, myScale);
```

and use concat to join both the animations

```
CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleAnim, transform);
```